# cancancan mock load_and_authorize_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, cancancan

I have a test where I stub a class "ClassA". And I want [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)'s [load_and_authorize_resource](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb#L37) to load my stubbed object, instead of fetching it from the database.

```
class ClassAController < ApplicationController
 load_and_authorize_resource :classa
end
```

I've tried different ways with [mocha](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Mock.html), but with no success

```
CanCan::ControllerResource.any_instance.stubs(:load_and_authorize_resource).returns(@stubbed_classA)
```

> does not load the @classA object, as is supposed to

Or, using [responds_like](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Mock.html#responds_like-instance_method)

```
  @stubb_classA = stub(...)
  ...
  class MOCKING
    def self.load_and_authorize_resource!
      @classa = @stubb_classA 
      returns true 
    end
  end

  CanCan::ControllerResource.any_instance.responds_like(MOCKING)
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `responds_like' for Mocha::ClassMethods::AnyInstance:0x00000006dfe958>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one takes a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb#L37), it ends up calling [find_resource](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb#L108), which uses an adapter pattern to find the appropiate instance.

I got it to work by stubbing an active_record class find method, be aware cancancan also has a find_by method, but in my case it worked with just stubbing find.

first you should stub authorization,  it can vary widely, in my case, the authorization was:

ability.rb

```
can :manage, ClassA do |w|
 w.user_workspaces.exists?(admin: true, user: user)  
end
```

so, because cancancan asks the object for authorization, the stub should be

```
 @stubbed_object.user_workspaces.stubs(:exists?).with(:admin => true, :user =>@user).returns(true)
```

Finally, stub the finder

```
#make ClassA return a stubbed object.
ClassA.stubs(:find).with(@stubbed_object.id).returns(@stubbed_object)
```

By the way, if someone's got an alternative, please post it.